# When I enter npm i can not install npm to this projecrt because this error is coming

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

> npm ERR! code ENOENT
>
> npm ERR! syscall open npm ERR! path C:\Users\Navodhya
> Yasisuru\OneDrive\Documents\portfolio_website-STARTER/package.json npm
> ERR! errno -4058 npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory,
> open 'C:\Users\Navodhya
> Yasisuru\OneDrive\Documents\portfolio_website-STARTER\package.json'
>
> npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
> npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\Navodhya
> Yasisuru\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-01-01T05_01_44_757Z-debug-0.log

I tried to run `npm i` in this project

Comment: select correct directory then run this command npm i. otherwise just check node is installed or not

Answer (score 2):

`npm i` or `npm install` requires a `package.json` file in your directory, but it couldn’t find it. My guess is you ran it without first running `npm init` to create it.

Important detail in error message:

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '...\package.json'

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused due to missing package.json. Possible reasons:

1. Not creating package.json for new npm module
2. Deleting it accidentally
3. Selecting invalid directory before running `npm i`

Answer (score 0):

i think you are missing package.json, create package.json with `npm init`